# 2005 Subaru Legacy Outback 3LR g H6

Tags: subaru, cooling-system, water-pump, dashboard

Tried burping radiator with no success. Water boils out but temp gauge reads normal??? 2005 Subaru Outback 3.0 H6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange overheating behaviour](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27991/strange-overheating-behaviour)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate IIRC the 3.0 doesn't have two coolant caps and only has the radiator cap and reservoir. OP also makes no mention of oil consumption.

Comment: As a start I'd get the cap tested to make sure it's holding pressure.